# Cannot break or build blocks in Minecraft creative mode Xbox one

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

My sister had forgotten her password to her old Xbox live account and got a new one and joined my creative world and couldn't break or build blocks. However, this did not happen to my brother even though he got a new account but it is hard to remember because he got his old account back. Anyway, my sister was in creative the whole time and her settings were on member. What is happening?